# Как сделать чтобы сообщения от всех логгеров с определенными именами не передавались выше?

Tags: java, логирование

Собственно задание:
Требуется выставить такие настройки, чтобы:

1. Логгер с именем `"org.example.java.logging.ClassA"` принимал сообщения всех уровней.
2. Логгер с именем `"org.example.java.logging.ClassB"` принимал только сообщения уровня WARNING и серьезнее.
3. Сообщения от всех логгеров с именами, начинающимися на `"org.example.java"`, независимо от уровня печатались в консоль в формате XML (*).
4. Сообщения от всех логгеров с именами, начинающимися на `"org.example.java"`, не передавались вышестоящим обработчикам ("org.example", "org" и "").

Проблема с 4 пунктом, остальные вроде должны работать.

```
public class Logs {

    private static void configureLogging() {
        Logger LOGGER1 = Logger.getLogger("org.example.java.logging.ClassA");
        Logger LOGGER2 = Logger.getLogger("org.example.java.logging.ClassB");
        Logger LOGGER3 = Logger.getLogger("org.example.java");

        LOGGER1.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        LOGGER2.setLevel(Level.WARNING);

        ConsoleHandler ch = new ConsoleHandler();
        LOGGER3.addHandler(ch);
    }

}
```

Comment: Думаю вам апендеры нужно правильно настроить и будет печататься как захотите. Т.е. требования нужно сформулировать с точки зрения: "что хочу видеть".

Comment: Это задача и ее проверяет валидатор. Так что есть только то что написано в условии(

Answer (score 3):

Решение вашей задачи выглядит следующим образом:

```
Logger logA = Logger.getLogger("org.example.java.logging.ClassA");
logA.setLevel(Level.ALL);

Logger logB = Logger.getLogger("org.example.java.logging.ClassB");
logB.setLevel(Level.WARNING);

Logger log = Logger.getLogger("org.example.java");
ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
handler.setFormatter(new XMLFormatter());
log.addHandler(handler);
log.setUseParentHandlers(false);
```